# Namespace Handling

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have one xsl file and 2 input xml files from which output is to be generated. In One XML file their are some namespaces which are imported to xsl file. But in other XML file the namespace doesn't exist. 
I have to handle my XSL in such a way that it can handle both XML files because XSL is common for both input XML files.
Please suggest.

Namespace in 1st XML file ->

```
<TreeList xmlns="urn:sfti:documents:BasicTreeList:1:0"    
xmlns:cac="urn:sfti:CommonAggregateComponents:1:0"  
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonBasicComponents:1:0" 
xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CoreComponentParameters:1:0" 
xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0" 
xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:SpecializedDatatypes:1:0" 
xmlns:udt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:UnspecializedDatatypes:1:0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Namespace in 2nd XML file ->

```
<TreeList xmlns:cac="urn:sfti:CommonAggregateComponents:1:0"  
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonBasicComponents:1:0" 
xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CoreComponentParameters:1:0" 
xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0" 
xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:SpecializedDatatypes:1:0" 
xmlns:udt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:UnspecializedDatatypes:1:0"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Namespace in XSL File ->

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    xmlns:abc="urn:sfti:documents:BasicTreeList:1:0" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:sfti:CommonAggregateComponents:1:0" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonBasicComponents:1:0">
```

When I run my XSL file it runs fine with 1st XML. But it doesn't work well with 2nd XML File due to namespace problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same XSLT code to process source documents that use the same local-names in their vocabulary, but different namespaces, then the best solution is to preprocess one of the files to change the namespaces. This can be done using a stylesheet containing templates such as these:

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='old-uri']">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new-uri">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri()='old-uri']">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" namespace="new-uri">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: As in the question I have multiple namespace so do I have to create multiple templates!

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read carefully enough. My advice is to preprocess the input so that it uses standardized namespaces. Then in your main processing step you don't have to deal with the unnecessary variety.